# "expulsar" div de su contenedor. dependiendo de la resolución de pantalla

Tags: html, css, responsive

Tengo la siguiente duda.

Yo tengo la siguiente estructura.

```
<div id="padre">
    <div id="hijo">

    </div>
</div>
```

Donde div hijo tiene el siguiente estilo css.

```
#hijo {
font-family: fina;
color: azure;
width: 180px;
height: 250px;
position: absolute;
left: 1%;
top: 1%;
background-color: azure;
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
border: 0px solid #000000;
}
```

lo que yo quiero hacer es que al tener X resolución de pantalla. Se ubique de la siguiente manera...

```
<div id="padre">        
</div>
<div id="hijo">    
</div>
```

Y el css del div #hijo quedaría así.

```
#hijo {
font-family: fina;
color: azure;
width: 100%;
height: 10%;
position: relative;
left: 0;
top: 0;
background-color: azure;
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
border: 0px solid #000000;
}
```

existe la posibilidad de hacer esto?

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya has probado con @media en css?

Comment: Hola. Lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera.

Comment: `<div id="padre">
    <div id="hijo">

    </div>
</div>`

Comment: Perdón, lo que hice, fue, sacar al DIV HIJO, del PADRE, y a los dos meterlos dentro de un contenedor, luego al hijo, lo ubiqué con "absolute", dentro del padre.

Answer (score 0):

La solución era fácil.

```
<div id="padre">
  <div id="hijo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo transformé en:

```
<div id="contenedor">
      <div id="padre">      
      </div>
      <div id="hijo">
      </div>
</div>
```

Luego, ubicamos el div "hijo" con position absolute